# C language for C8051F120 Silicon Labs

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to control a pin and set its logic level to '1' and then '0' (basically blinking an LED) but for some reason I can't even get this basic thing to work.

From digging around I found that I first need to set the bit/port to output mode and only then change the output level of the pin.

Here's my full code, and any sort of guidance would be very greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "inc\C8051F120.h"

sbit ON_BOARD_LED = P2^0;

void main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    P2MDOUT = 0xFF;

    while(1)
    {

        for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++);

        ON_BOARD_LED = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++);

        ON_BOARD_LED = 1;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong or where I could get more relevant information?

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: What do you expect this `P2^0` to do? I'm pretty sure your expectation is wrong...

Comment: Does your compiler support the oddball `P2^0` thing? I think some ancient 8051 toolchain used that as a non-standard extension but it's not valid C. In standard C you'd simply get an XOR instead, which is nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin
I forgot to mention I'm working on a very old MCU and I'm getting myself acquainted with it for some new projects at work.

The C8051F120.h contains the definition for this P2^0 and the compiler doesn't seem to complain, I've also tried working with P2 as a whole, same result either way.

Comment: Well, the sooner Silabs stops scamming people into buying 8051 still in the year 2022, the sooner mankind can move on to cores actually made after the year 1990... What's the toolchain here, Simplicity Studio? What compiler?

Comment: @Lundin It's my workplace that's the ancient one here, not Silabs. Still using Mercurial instead of Git, C8051.. and whatnot. I'm using Keil C51 toolchain, and I believe GCC is the compiler used. keil uVision3 is my IDE.

Comment: @Matt If it's Keil IDE then it's likely the Keil compiler. Can't help you there, though I believe it is one of them compilers supporting this non-standard syntax.

Comment: Oh right, the loops are actually completely broken and might be optimized out. Should be `for(volatile uint16_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++);`

Comment: What do you see? Compiler error/the LED being constantly off/...?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add, _how it does not work_. BTW, the backslash in a path for `#include` should be a forward slash. And Keil C51 has its own compiler, not GCC. It is old, has known errors, is non-compliant, but optimizes well; probably too well in your case. You can ask it about its version.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the maximum value for the loop. I think it´s too fast to be seen if the C8051F120 runs at 100MHz. Change to at least 10^8 to blink one second on , another off.

Also check the following. From https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/C8051F12x-13x.pdf

"The output drivers on Ports 0 through 3 remain disabled until the Crossbar is enabled by setting XBARE
(XBR2.4) to a logic 1." page 239

Try adding XBR2 = 0x40; before the P2MDOUT = 0xFF;

Comment: My apologies, I had forgotten to mention I've used breakpoints and a multi-meter to test whether the output is being changed, and it isn't, regardless of clock speed. But that is definitely a good thing to note, thank you!

Comment: multimeters have slower response time than the human eye.

Answer (score 0):

For the Keil C51 compiler you can create a slightly more accurate delay as follows (note that how the compiler decides to optimize the C code can vary *greatly* depending on your settings, so you will need to calibrate it if they change!)

Busy loop:

```
#include <intrins.h>

void wait(volatile uint32_t cnt) {
    while(cnt--)
        _nop_();
}
```

From the [Keil header file](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/c51/cygnal/c8051f120.h) the port definition is:

```
sfr P2            = 0xA0; /* PORT 2 LATCH */
```

From the [Keil compiler sbit page](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm)

```
sbit name = sfr-name ^ bit-position;
sbit name = sfr-address ^ bit-position;
sbit name = sbit-address;
```

So it seems your `P2^0` is correct.

Comment: " so changing something would change the delay" Yeah like switching to release build for example...

Comment: @Lundin updated using intrinsics instead, and a disclaimer